# conclude whether $ \ f(0) , \ f(4) , \ f(50), \ f(-5) , \ f(-100) \ $ are summable

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $ \ f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} \ $.

Then conclude whether $ \ f(0)  , \ f(4) , \ f(50), \ f(-5) , \ f(-100) \ $ are summable.

Plot the partial sums $ \ f(x) \ $ for $ \ N=4,20,100,101 \ $ and explain interval of convergence from the graphs.

**Answer:**

Since $ \ f(0)=0 \ $, it converges and hence $ \ f(0) \ $ is summable.

Since $ \ f(4)=\sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{4^n}{n!} \ $ diverges , $ \ f(4) \ $ is not   summable.

Since $ \ f(-5) =\sum_{0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{5^n}{n!} $ converges by Alternating series test , $ \ f(-5) \ $ is summable.

**Am I Right so far?**

Next I have drawn the graph of partial sums for $ N=5,20,100,101 \ $

as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**what does this imply for interval of convergence ?**

Comment: Can you justify each of your answers (especially $f(4)$ is not summable). Also have you ever heard of the exponential function?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, $f(x)$ is surely just $e^x$?

Comment: By ratio test $ \lim  | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} | =\frac{4^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \times \frac{n!}{4^n}=\frac{4}{n+1} \to 0 \ $ . So $ f(4) \ $ is summable. I did wrong.

Comment: so all $ \ f(0), \ f(4), f(50), f(-100) \ $ are summable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues. First of all, $f(4)$ is summable; I suggest using the ratio test. In fact, using the ratio test on all these values shows that these series are summable.

Second, I'd caution you in using the alternating series test. It's difficult to tell, since you haven't written much of your working, but the alternating series test requires not just that the series be alternating, but that the absolute value of the terms converge (as a sequence) **monotonically** to $0$. You need to establish that the sequence
$$\left|(-1)^n\frac{5^n}{n!}\right| = \frac{5^n}{n!} \to 0$$
as $n \to \infty$. Moreover, you need to establish that the sequence is monotone decreasing, i.e.
$$\frac{5^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \le \frac{5^n}{n!}$$
for all $n$. Unfortunately, this isn't the case, as
$$\frac{5^2}{2!} = 12.5 > 5 = \frac{5^1}{1!}.$$
Fortunately, it is possible to show that the sequence is eventually decreasing, which could save the argument, but there's some work that needs to be done first.

Third, while you're right about the convergence of $f(0)$, there is something you've overlooked: particularly the term where $n = 0$. The first term takes the form $\frac{0^0}{0!} = 0^0$, which is conventionally $1$ when looking at power series. So, the sum is, in fact, $1$.

Comment: How to compare the given series with a convergent geometric series (to be chosen) to say that the series is convergent? Please help

Comment: @MONJURALAM I'm not sure I understand you. The ratio test is usually how you compare a series with geometric series to prove convergence, and I can see that you know how to do it from your comment on the question. I don't really know what you're asking.

Comment: My question - what does the above graph of partial sums means regarding the interval of convergence ?  Does this means that the interval of convergence increases as $ \ N \ $ increases? Just clear my confusion

Comment: The graphs don't say much about the interval of convergence, really. The actual interval (which is all of $\mathbb{R}$) doesn't change, no matter how many functions you plot. They might give you an idea of when the approximation is reasonable, and when it's useless. For example, I would not estimate $f(40)$ with $N = 100$ terms.

Comment: But the question asked to discuss the behavior of interval of convergence by viewing the above graphs.  I think as $ \ N \ $ increases the inteval of convergence increases. Is not it true?

Comment: It's one power series with one interval of convergence. The interval of convergence doesn't increase or decrease, since it's a property of the *infinite* series, not the (finite) partial sums. Despite what the question says, I don't think there's any valid information to be gained about the (one and only) interval of convergence of the series by looking at graphs of partial sums.